# Ruby Lambda For Sorting by Multiple Parameters

Tags: ruby, sorting

I need to create lambdas for sort criteria.
To simplify the lambda creation process, I would like to order the comparisons consistently, for example:

```rb
[a.v1, b.v2] <=> [a.v1, b.v2]
[a.v1, b.v2] <=> [-a.v1, b.v2]
[a.v1, b.v2] <=> [a.v1, -b.v2]
[a.v1, b.v2] <=> [-a.v1, -b.v2]
```

To ensure that the lambdas work the way I expect, I wrote the following `rspec`:

```rb
class Obj
  attr_reader :v1, :v2, :v3

  def initialize(param1, param2, param3)
    @v1 = param1
    @v2 = param2
    @v3 = param3
  end
end

RSpec.describe(Array) do
  let(:o1) { Obj.new(1, 1, 1) }
  let(:o2) { Obj.new(2, 1, 1) }
  let(:o3) { Obj.new(2, 2, 1) }
  let(:o4) { Obj.new(3, 2, 1) }
  let(:objs) { [o1, o2, o3, o4] }

  # See https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Comparable.html
  it "uses comparators properly" do
    expect([o1.v1] <=> [o2.v1]).to eq(-1)
    expect([o1.v1, o1.v2] <=> [o2.v1, o2.v2]).to eq(-1)
    expect([o1.v2, o1.v1] <=> [o3.v1, o3.v2]).to eq(-1)
    expect([o1.v2, o1.v1] <=> [o3.v1, -o3.v2]).to eq(-1)
    expect([o2.v2, o1.v1] <=> [-o2.v2, o2.v1]).to eq(1)
    expect([o2.v2, o1.v1] <=> [-o2.v2, -o2.v1]).to eq(1)
  end

  # See https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort
  it "sorts by 2 keys, both ascending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [a.v1, a.v2] <=> [b.v1, b.v2] }
    result = objs.sort(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o1, o2, o3, o4])
  end

  it "sorts by 2 keys, both descending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [a.v1, a.v2] <=> [-b.v1, -b.v2] }
    result = objs.sort(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o4, o3, o2, o1])
  end

  it "sorts by 2 keys, first descending and second ascending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [a.v1, b.v2] <=> [-a.v1, b.v2] }
    result = objs.sort(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o4, o3, o2, o1])
  end

  # This one fails ... why?
  it "sorts by 2 keys, first ascending and second descending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [a.v1, b.v2] <=> [a.v1, -b.v2] }
    result = objs.sort(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o1, o3, o2, o4])
  end
end
```

The tests all pass, except the last one, which fails with:

```
Failure/Error: expect(result).to eq([o1, o3, o2, o4])

expected: [#<Obj:0x00007fc2ac112940 @v1=1, @v2=1, @v3=1>, #<Obj:0x00007fc2ac112828 @v1=2, @v2=2, @v3=1>, #<Obj:0x00007fc2ac1128c8 @v1=2, @v2=1, @v3=1>, #<Obj:0x00007fc2ac112788 @v1=3, @v2=2, @v3=1>]
     got: [#<Obj:0x00007fc2ac112788 @v1=3, @v2=2, @v3=1>, #<Obj:0x00007fc2ac112828 @v1=2, @v2=2, @v3=1>, #<Obj:0x00007fc2ac1128c8 @v1=2, @v2=1, @v3=1>, #<Obj:0x00007fc2ac112940 @v1=1, @v2=1, @v3=1>]
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answers fail when applying a descending sort according to `Date` field(s). This solution uses the suggestion from @ngineersmnky to reverse the comparison order for fields that need to be sorted in descending order.

Note that although `sort_by` is more convenient to use than `sort`, only `sort` provides the ability to reverse the order of comparison, so it must be used for this solution, and not `sort_by`.

```rb
class Obj
  # `date_modified` is primary sort key
  # `date` (when specified) is secondary sort key
  attr_reader :date, :date_modified

  def initialize(param1, param2)
    @date_modified = Date.parse(param1)
    @date = Date.parse(param2)
  end
end

RSpec.describe(Obj) do
  let(:o1) { Obj.new('2000-01-01', '2001-01-01') }
  let(:o2) { Obj.new('2010-01-01', '2001-01-01') }
  let(:o3) { Obj.new('2010-01-01', '2011-01-01') }
  let(:o4) { Obj.new('2020-01-01', '2011-01-01') }
  let(:objs) { [o1, o2, o3, o4] }

  # See https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Comparable.html
  it "compares one key with ascending dates" do
    expect([o1.date_modified] <=> [o2.date_modified]).to eq(-1)
    expect([o2.date_modified] <=> [o3.date_modified]).to eq(0)
    expect([o3.date_modified] <=> [o4.date_modified]).to eq(-1)
  end

  it "compares two keys with ascending dates" do
    expect([o1.date_modified, o1.date] <=> [o2.date_modified, o2.date]).to eq(-1)
    expect([o2.date_modified, o2.date] <=> [o3.date_modified, o3.date]).to eq(-1)
    expect([o3.date_modified, o3.date] <=> [o4.date_modified, o4.date]).to eq(-1)
  end

  it "compares one key with descending dates" do
    expect([o1.date_modified] <=> [o2.date_modified]).to eq(-1)
    expect([o2.date_modified] <=> [o3.date_modified]).to eq(0)
  end

  it "compares two keys with descending dates" do
    expect([o2.date_modified, o2.date] <=> [o1.date_modified, o1.date]).to eq(1)
    expect([o3.date_modified, o3.date] <=> [o2.date_modified, o2.date]).to eq(1)
    expect([o4.date_modified, o4.date] <=> [o3.date_modified, o3.date]).to eq(1)
  end

  # See https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort
  it "sort with both keys ascending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [a.date_modified, a.date] <=> [b.date_modified, b.date] }
    result = objs.sort(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o1, o2, o3, o4])
  end

  it "sort with both keys descending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [b.date_modified, b.date] <=> [a.date_modified, a.date] }
    result = objs.sort(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o4, o3, o2, o1])
  end

  it "sort with date_modified descending and date ascending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [b.date_modified, a.date] <=> [a.date_modified, b.date] }
    result = objs.sort(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o4, o2, o3, o1])
  end

  it "sort with date_modified ascending and date descending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [a.date_modified, b.date] <=> [b.date_modified, a.date] }
    result = objs.sort(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o1, o3, o2, o4])
  end
end
```

Comment: So just so I understand this correctly. I answered the actual question posed; then solved your date issue in the comments and in turn you marked your own answer as correct while giving me credit? Just to be clear I don't care about the reputation points but that tactic is uncouth at best bordering on offensive. I'm glad I helped you but wow!

Comment: Your suggestions were right on. However, I felt that this question, like all questions, deserved a proper answer, with a full code example. It is the difference between giving suggestions and showing exactly what you mean. If you copy-paste my code, or similar code you wrote, into your answer, I will check yours answer again.

Comment: Okay excepting that's not the question you asked nor does your answer actually provide any context without mine. Either way at least I understand *why* now. 

Answer (score 2):

I think you might misunderstand how `Array#<=>` (spaceship) works. (or maybe it is just a typo in your tests)

What this does is sort by `a[0] <=> b[0]` and if that is `0` (equal) then it moves on to `a[1] <=> b[1]` and so on until `(x <=> y) != 0`; however it will only compare a set once meaning 4 elements 4 iterations. This causes an issue for you because it means that it will never have a set of comparisons where `a == o2 && b == o3` and then also `a == o3 && b == o2`

In your failing test:

```
sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [a.v1, b.v2] <=> [a.v1, -b.v2] }
```

`a.v1` will always equal `a.v1` e.g. return `0` so it moves on to comparing `b.v2` to `-b.v2` and you end up with `b.v2` in descending order.

It appears what you actually wanted is

```
sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [a.v1, -a.v2] <=> [b.v1, -b.v2] }
```

Example:

```
a = [[1,1,1],[2,1,1],[2,2,1],[3,2,1]]
sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [a.v1, -a.v2] <=> [b.v1, -b.v2] }
a.sort(&sort_lambda)
#=> [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1], [3, 2, 1]]
```

**Notes:**

1. All your tests suffer from a very specific issue which is that the operator needs to be applied to both sides. For example *it "sorts by 2 keys, both descending"* appears to pass but this is only due to the order in which you have presented the arguments. e.g.

```
sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [a[0], a[1]] <=> [-b[0], -b[1]] }
a.sort(&sort_lambda)
#=> [[3, 2, 1], [2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]] #looks like it works 
b = [a[0],a[2],a[1],a[3]] 
b.sort(&sort_lambda)
#=> [[3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]] # Oh No 
b.sort(&sort_lambda) == a.sort(&sort_lambda) #=> false
# apply the same unary on both sides 
sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [-a[0], -a[1]] <=> [-b[0], -b[1]] }
b.sort(&sort_lambda)
#=> [[3, 2, 1], [2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]] # that's better 
b.sort(&sort_lambda) == a.sort(&sort_lambda) #=> true
```

2. The *it "sorts by 2 keys, first descending and second ascending"* test is wrong but because your expectation (`[o4, o3, o2, o1]`) is incorrect the test passes. Based on the test description the expected output should be `[o4, o2, o3, o1]` and the lambda body should change to `[-a.v1, a.v2] <=> [-b.v1, b.v2]`
3. These tests are easier expressed using `sort_by` e.g. `sort_by {|a| [-a.v1,a.v2]}`

Comment: Well done! Thanks for catching the copy-paste errors, and the excellent explanations. Your comment "apply the same unary on both sides" was also very helpful. The lambda for `sort_by` would be simpler.

Comment: Descending sorts fail when a comparison field has type Date with error `undefined method `-@' for #<Date: 2020-01-01 ((2458850j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`

Comment: @MikeSlinn another way to sort in descending order is to reverse the arguments `->(a,b) { b<=>a }`

Comment: Yes, others have done that. I was initially resistant to that approach because of the extra complexity necessary to make the necessary lambdas. However, the only other way I was able to make this work with dates was to format to `YYYY-MM-DD`, and that has similar or worse complexity.

Comment: Reversing the arguments only works with `sort`, not `sort_by`.

Comment: @MikeSlinn correct you cannot use `sort` to create a descending order for a `Date` without conversion e.g. `->(a) { -a.to_time.to_i }`, `->(a) { -a.strftime('%s').to_i }`, `->(a) {-a.jd}`, etc. because `Date` does not have unary inversion (`-@`)

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, here is the answer with @engineersmnky's corrections. Both a `sort` and an equivalent `sort_by` approach is provided for each scenario.

```rb
class Obj
  attr_reader :v1, :v2, :v3

  def initialize(param1, param2, param3)
    @v1 = param1
    @v2 = param2
    @v3 = param3
  end
end

RSpec.describe(Array) do # rubocop:disable Metrics/BlockLength
  let(:o1) { Obj.new(1, 1, 1) }
  let(:o2) { Obj.new(2, 1, 1) }
  let(:o3) { Obj.new(2, 2, 1) }
  let(:o4) { Obj.new(3, 2, 1) }
  let(:objs) { [o1, o2, o3, o4] }

  # See https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Comparable.html
  it "uses comparators properly" do
    expect([o1.v1] <=> [o2.v1]).to eq(-1)
    expect([o1.v1, o1.v2] <=> [o2.v1, o2.v2]).to eq(-1)
    expect([o1.v2, o1.v1] <=> [o3.v1, o3.v2]).to eq(-1)
    expect([o1.v2, o1.v1] <=> [o3.v1, -o3.v2]).to eq(-1)
    expect([o2.v2, o1.v1] <=> [-o2.v2, o2.v1]).to eq(1)
    expect([o2.v2, o1.v1] <=> [-o2.v2, -o2.v1]).to eq(1)
  end

  # See https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort
  it "sort with 2 keys, both ascending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [a.v1, a.v2] <=> [b.v1, b.v2] }
    result = objs.sort(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o1, o2, o3, o4])
  end

  it "sort_by with 2 keys, both ascending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a) { [a.v1, a.v2] }
    result = objs.sort_by(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o1, o2, o3, o4])
  end

  it "sort with 2 keys, both descending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [-a.v1, -a.v2] <=> [-b.v1, -b.v2] }
    result = objs.sort(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o4, o3, o2, o1])
  end

  it "sort_by with 2 keys, both descending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a) { [-a.v1, -a.v2] }
    result = objs.sort_by(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o4, o3, o2, o1])
  end

  it "sort with 2 keys, first descending and second ascending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [-a.v1, a.v2] <=> [-b.v1, b.v2] }
    result = objs.sort(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o4, o2, o3, o1])
  end

  it "sort_by with 2 keys, first descending and second ascending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a) { [-a.v1, a.v2] }
    result = objs.sort_by(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o4, o2, o3, o1])
  end

  it "sort with 2 keys, first ascending and second descending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a, b) { [a.v1, -a.v2] <=> [b.v1, -b.v2] }
    result = objs.sort(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o1, o3, o2, o4])
  end

  it "sort_by with 2 keys, first ascending and second descending" do
    sort_lambda = ->(a) { [a.v1, -a.v2] }
    result = objs.sort_by(&sort_lambda)
    expect(result).to eq([o1, o3, o2, o4])
  end
end
```

This solution throws an exception if a property of type `Date` is used as a descending sort key. The error message of the form `undefined method` -@' for #<Date: 2011-01-01 ((2455563j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`.

To see the error:

1. Modify `initialize` to be:

   ```rb
   def initialize(param1, param2)
     @v1 = Date.parse(param1)
     @v2 = Date.parse(param2)
     @v3 = param3
   end
   ```
2. Modify the definitions of `o1` .. `o4` to be of the form:

   ```rb
   let(:o1) { Obj.new('2000-01-01', '2001-01-01', 1) }
   let(:o2) { Obj.new('2010-01-01', '2001-01-01', 1) }
   let(:o3) { Obj.new('2010-01-01', '2011-01-01', 1) }
   let(:o4) { Obj.new('2020-01-01', '2011-01-01', 1) }
   let(:objs) { [o1, o2, o3, o4] }
   ```